# Sending emails via Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have a pet project and all I want is to have the server send me a status email every day that everything updated smoothly etc. Gmail used to let you use their SMTP server with just a login but have since changed to OAuth. I'm following this [tutorial](https://mailtrap.io/blog/python-send-email-gmail/):

```
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from requests import HTTPError

SCOPES = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
    ]
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
message = MIMEText('This is the body of the email')
message['to'] = 'recipient@gmail.com'
message['subject'] = 'Email Subject'
create_message = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}

try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
    print(F'sent message to {message} Message Id: {message["id"]}')
except HTTPError as error:
    print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
    message = None
```

I have setup a project and an application in Google Cloud, and have downloaded the credentials.json file. I have also added myself as a test user in APIs & Services > OAuth consent screen > Test users. Now, every time I run the above code, it's asking me to consent first, which I thought is what the test user is supposed to circumvent. How do I authorise a test app?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, in your situation, how about storing the refresh token in a file and retrieving the access token using the refresh token when the script is run after 2nd run? By this, you are not required to authorize the scopes using the browser again after 2nd run. In that case, is this sample script of the official document useful? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Even though this may be a temporary solution as every now and then I will need to log into the server and refresh the token as the token has a set expiry?

Comment: if you store the refresh token your code could request a new access token when it needs.

Answer (score 0):

"Google will display a warning message before allowing a specified test user to authorize scopes requested by your project's OAuth clients. The warning message confirms the user has test access to your project but should consider the risks associated with granting access to their data to an unverified app."

[Setting up your OAuth consent screen - Testing](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en&sjid=2541178150838316043-NC#zippy=%2Ctesting)